# unrar from subfolders and rename to parent folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

With a batch file I'd like to be able to unrar all .rar files in subfolders from one specified folder "c:\files". There is a single .txt file inside each rar file that I need to be renamed to it's original rar folder name, this file needs to be with it's original rar file. I'll try to explain..

```
c:\files\rarfolder1\1.rar
c:\files\rarfolder2\2.rar
c:\files\rarfolder3\3.rar
c:\files\rarfolder4\4.rar
```

Then becomes

```
c:\files\rarfolder1\rarfolder1.txt
c:\files\rarfolder2\rarfolder2.txt
c:\files\rarfolder3\rarfolder3.txt
c:\files\rarfolder4\rarfolder4.txt
```

The folder locations might change as well as the file types inside the rar files.

Comment: do you want the rar file deleted?  Will there only be a single rar file in each folder and nothing else?

Comment: The rar file needs to stay where it is and the rar archive is split into a bunch of files so there's a bunch of other files in the directory

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you on the command line:

```
for /r "c:\files" %a in (*.rar *.txt) do @for %i in ("%~pa.") do @if /i "%~xa"==".rar" (echo winrar -x "%~fa") else echo ren "%~fa" "%~ni%~xa"
```

Comment: I get the following erro back. The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~pa.") do @if /i "%~xa"==".rar" (echo winrar -x "%~fa") else echo ren "%~fa" "%~ni%~xa"

Comment: you must double all percent signs, eg.: `"%%~pa"`

Comment: Ah ok, sorry my mistake. I've also noticed that I have some directories with more than one rar file in, I only need to extract the first file. The files are labelled archive.part001.rar archive.part002.rar archive.part003.rar archive.part003.rar and this script unpacks the archive successfully but then tries to start from archive.part002.rar etc etc. Is it possible to make it skip to the next directory after it has extracted from the first rar file?

Comment: you can change `(*.rar *.txt)` to `(*part001.rar *.txt)` .

Comment: Ok that's working now but I need to have the extracted files in the same location as the rar files?